# Is it possible to have Tab Bar with content before in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I just wanted to ask, if it is possible to have Tab Bar View in Flutter with content before tabs (I mean that the Tabs are for example in the middle of the screen and they have content before - e.g. profile information - like Instagram and its profile section).

[Example of what I mean here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDvSf.png)

I have already tried the default Tab View, but it is not what I want.

```dart
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      flexibleSpace: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.teal,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),

            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black45,
            unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
            ),

            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.list)
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.map)
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),

    body: TabBarView(
      children: <Widget>[

        Container(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 100,
                child: Text('Hello'),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),

        Container(
          child: Text('testuju'),
        )

      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Is it even possible to do it with Tab View, or should I fake tabs with styled buttons? Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes this is possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
              bottom: TabBar(
                controller: tabController,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Text("Login"),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Text("Sign Up"),
                  ),
                ],
                indicatorColor: Colors.black,
              ),
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Colors.red,
                      Colors.orange,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(200.0),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: [
              LoginApp(),
              SignUpApp(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try that:

```
Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        initialIndex: // initial tab,
        length: // tabs numbers,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (buildContext, isScrolled){
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                primary: true,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                actions: <Widget>[
                  BackBtnIcon(action: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 6,),
                ],
                title: Text(memberFullName),
              ),
              SliverPadding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                sliver: SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                    [
                      Container(
                        color: CopticColors.mainButtonColor,
                        child: CustomTabBar()
                      ),
                    ]
                  )
                ),
              )
            ];
          },
          body: SafeArea(
                      minimum: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: TabBarView(
//                    physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        children: [ // replace with your tabs
                          ConfessionTab(model: snapshot.data,),
                          CommunicationDetails(model: snapshot.data,),
                          GeneralDetails(model: snapshot.data,),
                          ChurchDetails(model: snapshot.data,),
                          GovDetails(model: snapshot.data,),
                        ],
                      )
        )
      ),
    );
```